# Does RxNetty support proxy for http client

Tags: java, proxy, rx-java, rx-netty

Does RxNetty support connecting to a server through proxy ? If yes could you please share usage example.

I looked at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/blob/0.5.x/rxnetty-examples/HTTP.md, But couldn't deduce anything from the examples.

Comment: did you get any update on this , I was also looking for the same info .